# Does "talking nonsense" also mean saying words that no-one can understand?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

According to my study, it seems that "**he is talking nonsense!**" means he is saying a belief or an idea that is not true.

For example, Bob says "**men can give birth**".

Most people can understand the meaning of the above statement, but most people think the statement is not true, so "**he is talking nonsense!**".

My question is that, suppose Bob says "**bre ba ba boo breet....**" (**1**) like a sound of a bird or his English is messed up says this "**Have no table good stuff fall jump out**" (**2**).

The first sentence sounds like a bird voice and the second sentence is a combination of English words together in such a way that is impossible to understand.

*Do we say "**he is talking nonsense!**" for the 1st and the second sentence above?*

Comment: Tom, you should know by now that you need to look in a dictionary before asking a question. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nonsense

Comment: The _primary_ meaning of 'non-sense' is something that doesn't make sense, not something that isn't true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the word "nonsense", but if the person was coming out with a stream of obviously made-up words, you might be more likely to say that they were talking "gibberish".

Oxford defines "gibberish" as "Unintelligible or meaningless speech or writing; nonsense." ( https://www.lexico.com/definition/gibberish )

There is no clear-cut distinction, but "gibberish" would be the more usual term colloquially if your friend was saying "Bre ba Boo breet".

There is, though, a type of poetry known as "nonsense verse", where many of the words are made up ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabberwocky ).

Comment: +1 for 'gibberish'. People who have never heard the word spoken might find it useful to know that the initial 'g' is soft like in giant, geography, etc.